# session php rand other values

Tags: php, session

i have since two days the same error and i dont know how to fix that.

if i connect the first time to my webside i get other rand() numbers - as i reload my webside a second or a third time ...

index.php/

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {  session_start();  }
require_once('token.php');


var_dump($_SESSION['tok']);
```

token.php/

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {  session_start();  }

if(!isset($_SESSION['tok'])) { $_SESSION['tok'] = rand();}
```

Comment: What error? What is your question?

Comment: That's what **rand** stands for: **random**, i.e. (in the best case) every time the rand function is called it returns a different value. Set the **session_start();** statement at top of _index.php_ without any condition (if).

Comment: @jayBlanchard  hey - my question is how can i fix that that the session has all the times the same random numbers until i destroy the session

Comment: That is the thing about random numbers - they can be the same.

Comment: @hherger hello - i know what rand is but the strange thing is if i reload my webside a 2 time or a 3 time the rand session has the same value

Comment: @jayBlanchard but if i make them into a if statemant the script normally don´t overwrite them or?? because if i reload my webside a 2 time or a 3 time the rand session has the same value

Comment: I understood from your question "...i get other rand() numbers - as i reload..." that you get _different_ values. But, as Jay Blanchard said, random numbers can be the same, there's no guarantee they are different.

Comment: @hherger you understand my question correctly but - if i make a if statement if(!isset($_SESSION['tok'])) { $_SESSION['tok'] = rand();} the script normally don´t overwrite them or ???

Comment: Yes, it gets overwritten.

Comment: @jayBlanchard - thx for your answer ;-) but i don´t unterstand why it works after the 2 second reload

Comment: Try specifying a minimum and maximum range for `rand()`

Comment: it doesn´t work with your idear :-(

Comment: @RyanVincent hi thanks for your answer, i have my code checked with this var_dum () and is this normal that the PHPSESSID is not set at the first connection on  a webside ??? because after the second reload i have the PHPSESSID as array and at the Sessions are working correctly ??

Comment: @RyanVincent the session is only changing after the second reload of the webside until then the session has the same value as the session on the second reload --- its really strange .-)

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks a lot!

Comment: Website: http://rfv123.eu.pn/tok/.  [Clear current tok value](http://rfv123.eu.pn/tok/?reset).  [Destroy Session and Session Cookie](http://rfv123.eu.pn/tok/?session). Source code: [index.php and token.php](http://pastebin.com/VzXRunG2)

Comment: This was well worth doing as I now understand rather more about how to control sessions and their cookie.

Comment: @RyanVincent hi- i had test the script on your webside the script works fine but if i kopie them inside my webside i have the same problem with the session ... so which php.ini configuration do you have

Comment: You can see the website session settings at: http://rfv123.eu.pn/test.php. My local PHP.INI : http://pastebin.com/sGcTSNeJ. I use XAMPP 1.8.0, PHP 5.4 on windows. The setting are standard. Sessions in files with lifetime of about 30 minutes (1800 seconds). Those scripts were developed on my local PC and just copied to the website and pastebin.com.