# Session variable not set within functions

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm trying to set a session variable to record when people have voted but PHP is flat out refusing to set it. The code is as follows:

```
elseif (isset($_GET['group']) && isset($_GET['vote']))
    {
        include_once(_INC.'otherheader.php');
        groupVotePage($group, $vote);
        $_SESSION[$group] = '1';
        echo $_SESSION[$group];
    }
```

Nothing. The function groupVotePage adds the vote to the database and echoes a thanks message. $group is the name of the group being voted for. I have session_start(); at the top of the page and have tried to declare the variable inside the function called as well, putting session_start(); everywhere. Session variables are used elsewhere on the site so I know it's not a server issue, and it's the same on all browsers I tried.

Declaring the session var inside the function works but only within the function - it doesn't go global.

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION[$group])) {
        $totalVote=$totalVote+$vote;
        $totalNumVotes=$totalNumVotes+1;
        $totalRating=round($totalVote/$totalNumVotes);
        $totalScore=$totalVote*$totalNumVotes;
        ...db stuff...

        $mysqli->query($query);

        echo'Thanks for voting!';
    }

    else {
        echo'You have already voted for this group!';
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's ever reaching that condition?

Comment: You should show where `$group` is getting its value and consider doing a `var_dump` on `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Both $group and $vote are user selected and properly escaped, the whole function runs like clockwork so I know variables are being passed. Declaring the session var inside the function works but only within the function - it doesn't go global.

Comment: Your comment about putting session start everywhere is interesting. I would expect to see error messages due to trying to start the session more than once. Would you interested in ensuring that the session is always started once only and that you will see all errors? if so follow the instructions: [Create a simple application bootstrap file](http://pastebin.com/WeTDsUir). Remove all `session_start();` instructions from your current script. Now, 1) session is always started 2) you will see errors. Treat `notices` as errors and fix them.Then  we can fix what is wrong with your current script.

Comment: maybe interesting?  In another question with session issues similar to yours, I put a website together, with simple code, that looks after sessions: Website: [rfv123.eu.pn/tok](http://rfv123.eu.pn/tok/). [Clear current tok value](http://rfv123.eu.pn/tok/?reset). [Destroy Session and Session Cookie](http://rfv123.eu.pn/tok/?session). [Source code: index.php and token.php](http://pastebin.com/VzXRunG2). Original Question: [session php rand other values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271252/session-php-rand-other-values).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use PHP error reporting code to figure out where you going wrong

```
// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay fixed it, the < !DOCTYPE HTML> section was before the session_start();, when I put it after the code worked.